# Background network checking

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I have an app that displays the network availability whenever there is some activity such as the view change. However i am looking for a code that runs in the background to check the network availability even if i will be idle on the same screen and it must display a message that "network is not available/network is available"

Answer (score 2):

I use this piece of code to detect network availability. I basically declare local vars to figure out the things like whether I am on WiFi or 3G network or whether internet is available.

Notifications come at some intervals & update these variables. You access these BOOL vars to know the status.

```
- (void)checkNetworkStatus:(NSNotification *)notice
{
    // called after network status changes
    NetworkStatus internetStatus = [internetReachable currentReachabilityStatus];

    switch(internetStatus)
    {
        case NotReachable:
        {
            //NSLog(@"The internet is down.");
            self.internetActive = NO;
            break;
        }
        case ReachableViaWiFi:
        {
            //NSLog(@"The internet is working via WIFI.");
            self.internetActive = YES;
            break;
        }
        case ReachableViaWWAN:
        {
            //NSLog(@"The internet is working via WWAN.");
            self.internetActive = YES;
            break;
        }
    }

    NetworkStatus hostStatus = [hostReachable currentReachabilityStatus];
    switch (hostStatus)
    {
        case NotReachable:
        {
            //NSLog(@"A gateway to the host server is down.");
            self.hostActive = NO;
            break;
        }
        case ReachableViaWiFi:
        {
            //NSLog(@"A gateway to the host server is working via WIFI.");
            self.hostActive = YES;
            break;
        }
        case ReachableViaWWAN:
        {
            //NSLog(@"A gateway to the host server is working via WWAN.");
            self.hostActive = YES;
            break;
        }
    }
    return;
}
```